# PHP if statement problems

Tags: php, if-statement, hide, show

I have this statement written on my page:

```
<?php 
    if( get_theme_mod( 'img-upload-logo' ) ) { // CUSTOMIZER LOGO ?>  
       <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" rel="home">
          <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'img-upload-logo' )?>" class="logo-uploaded" alt="logo"/>
       </a>
<?php 
    } else { 
?> 

<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" rel="home">
    <h1 class="logo_text"><?php bloginfo( $name ); ?></h1></a>

<?php 
    } 
?>
```

Which simply calls a small logo uploaded behind the scenes or if no logo is present shows text, I have though added this line above the other 2:

```
<?php 
    if (is_page_template('page-home.php') )  { 
?>
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="Welcome" rel="home">
    <img src="http://www.webteam.cornwallitservices.nhs.uk/wp-content/themes/krative-child/assets/images/logolarger.png" class="logolarger" alt="logo"/>
 </a>
<?php 
    } else 
?>
```

This effectively shows a larger version of the logo as well but only on the homepage and then the smaller logo appears throughout the website.

Can anyone tell me please how to change this code so that it only shows the large logo on the homepage and not both logos - I'm missing some sort of if or statement I think.

Rich

Comment: Not reading the article, but why do you call multiple <?php ?> isn't it easier to call once php and then just echo the html you wish? + then you would not have those chances to make a mistake in IF statement :)

Comment: Sure, i'm not the best at PHP please feel free to re-write it for me :-)

Comment: Thank you Ofir, typical been staring at that for ages, 1 bracket lol - cheers

Comment: @YourCommonSense so calling 10times <?php is "easier" than to call it once and just echo it? this has just 10 lines and he is confused, now take 100 lines.

Comment: @WigglerJtag please, make yourself familiar with *templates*. Thank you.